# Is it a good practice to throw Exception inside setters in Java?

Tags: java, oop, setter, getter, getter-setter

To be more specific, I want to write a code that throws `IllegalArgumentException` if the given value is negative. Should I include this code inside of setter/constructor or should I check the value when the appropriate method is called? (Eg: `start()`, `init()`, `print()` or `run()`. whatever.)

My code (simplified):

```
public class LLUAlgorithm {

private int temperature;

public int getTemperature() {
    return temperature;
}

public void setTemperature(int temperature) {
    if (temperature < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("can't be smaller than 0.")
    this.temperature = temperature;
}

public void run() {
    ...
}
```

I don't recall a single case that a setter throws an exception as above. But I'm curious if it is good / bad.

Comment: Well, the exception name contains _illegal argument_, so of course you can throw it, when an argument was illegal, like a negative number. And yes, this can happen in a setter and I never heard, that this would be bad practice (because it isn't).

Comment: yes, it is ok, you could even try to be more specific with the exception... if is null, if is invalid index or define the custom exception

Comment: You should throw IllegalArgumentException. You can overdo it with a builder pattern. Did you read the book "Effective Java", that has material about the builder pattern.

Comment: Yes, throw the exception in the setter. If your code throws `IllegalArgumentException` at some later point in time, it would be confusing to the caller. From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html): `Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.`

Comment: I think its good to put exception in setters in to give the model itself to ability to talk about the error no matter how many times the model has been used. also reduce amount of exception handling each time you use that. Moreover if you can think of exposing APIs, thats also sounds good enough to put exception in setter

Comment: Yes this is good style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach is to make your object **immutable**, get rid of your setters and throws your exception in the constructor otherwise whatever the way you choose, in case of an error, you have a high risk to have your object in an inconsistent state which will cause hard bug to find. For a better understanding, please read [this](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/09/objects-should-be-immutable.html) especially the section related to `Failure Atomicity`.

Comment: So I get the idea. If I remove the setter in my case and put the exception inside the constructor, then the object won't even be created. Otherwise, the object will be in a broken state. Thanks a lot, for both the answer and the link.